# Python:- Return preorder Traversal from the given inorder traversal

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-tree

I'm going through Algorithmic questions and stumbled upon the following question:-

```
Given an inorder traversal of a binary tree, return preorder traversal
```

For eg:-

Inorder - `[16, 10, 4, 15, 28]` should return preorder `[4, 10, 16, 15, 28]`.

I google it, but couldnt find any solution. How can I get the preorder traversal?

Comment: If you know the input is in "inorder". Construct the tree and then do preorder traversal

Comment: But I'll be having multiple binary trees with given inorder traversal.

Comment: "In general, a single tree traversal does not uniquely define the
structure of the tree." See http://www.cmi.ac.in/~madhavan/courses/programming06/lecture12-21sep2006.txt

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following 2 trees, they have the same in-order but different pre-order traversals. The output pre-order traversal you provided starts with 4 means the node 4 must be the root of the tree, but the in-order traversal you provided does not guarantee a tree with node 4 as the root.

[image]

Comment: These appear to not be binary trees.

Comment: Then what kind of trees they are @Marichyasana ?

Comment: Excuse me, I was thinking of a binary search tree. For a BST the keys in the left subtree are less then the key in its parent node, in short L < P;
the keys in the right subtree are greater the key in its parent node, in short P < R;

Comment: OP mentioned binary tree, not a BST.